# TypeError during assert_no_difference test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**The issue**
I am writing unit tests for a RoR API, and I would like to test some entries from the response's body (something I have already done for another controller).
Basically, for an `index` method, I wanna check that every sub-element included in `data` share the same id as a specific one. Here is the complete test for the `index` method :

```rb
  test "should access Membership index - specifix team" do
    get api_v1_team_memberships_url(@team),
    headers: { Authorization: JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: @user.id) }, 
    as: :json
    assert_response :success
   
    json_response = JSON.parse(self.response.body)
    assert_no_difference @membership.member_id, json_response['data']['attributes']['member_id']
  end
```

But whatever I try, I get the very same error stack saying I have an issue with data type :

```
Error:                                                                                                    
Api::V1::MembershipsControllerTest#test_should_access_Membership_index_-_specifix_team:                   
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer                                                  
    test/controllers/api/v1/memberships_controller_test.rb:20:in `[]'                                     
    test/controllers/api/v1/memberships_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:MembershipsControllerTes
t>'
```

I really don't get why, since, as I said above, that's a check I've already done for some other controllers.

```rb
assert_equal @task.activity_id, json_response['data']['attributes']['activity_id']
```

**What I have tried so far**

- convert both element from the `assert_no_difference` function to string (`to_s`) or to integer (`to_i`)
- use `assert_equal` instead of `assert_no_difference`

Comment: assert_equal is what you should be using here. I'd print out the values of both the expected id and the response id and see what the types are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

is commonly caused by trying to get a value from an array by a string index. For example, the following will raise the same error

```
a = [1, 2]
puts a['test']
```

In your case, I suspect `json_response` or `json_response['data']` is an array.

Also, I believe you want to use `assert_equal` instead of `assert_no_difference`. `assert_no_difference` takes a numeric expression and a block; and asserts the expression is the same before and after the block is executed. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.2.2/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_no_difference

Comment: Oh of course that was it ... I forgot I was working with an array. Thanks !